# Jquery Map Array Keys and Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I've looked into this on other StackOverFlow Questions and I can't seem to find the answer.

I have a form.

```
<input name="item[1]" class="item" value="1">
<input name="item[2]" class="item" value="50">
<input name="item[3]" class="item" value="12">
```

I'm trying to get the results of each item input and send them via Ajax to my controller, this is fine when using the form action="" method but via ajax I can't seem to format the data in the array format.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

```
$('button#despatchOrder').on('click', function() {

    var values = $("input.items");

    var myArray = $.map(values, function(value, index) {
       return [value];
    });

    console.log(myArray);

});
```

Unfortunately Jquery isn't my strongest language but I'm learning. I was expecting the output to be something like.

```
items = [
 1 => 1,
 2 => 50,
 3 => 12
]
```

But I have everything associated to the input like

```
Input 1 = [
accept
accessKey
alt 
etc
etc
]
```

Comment: *"Unfortunately Jquery isn't my strongest language"* jQuery isn't a language at all, it's a library of utility functions. The *language* you're using is JavaScript.

Comment: first read about javascript arrays and then get back here if you have another problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Very little! :-)

- In your `$.map` callback, the first argument will be the *element*, not its value, so you just use its `value` property.
- You also were wrapping it in an array (`return [value]`), which you don't want to do; `$.map` will build an array from the values you return from each call to the callback.
- Also, you were using `input.items` where you wanted `input.item`.
- You don't need to declare the `index` argument if you don't use it.

  $('button#despatchOrder').on('click', function() {

  ```
  var values = $("input.item");                          // ***

  var myArray = $.map(values, function(element) {        // ***
     return element.value;                               // ***
  });

  console.log(myArray);
  ```

  });

Example:

```js
$('button#despatchOrder').on('click', function() {
    var values = $("input.item");
    var myArray = $.map(values, function(element) {
       return element.value;
    });
    console.log(myArray);
});
```

```html
<input name="item[1]" class="item" value="1">
<input name="item[2]" class="item" value="50">
<input name="item[3]" class="item" value="12">
<button id="despatchOrder">Despatch</button><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That gives you the items in the array *without* using the `item[1]` and such name. What you've shown that you want

```
items = [
 1 => 1,
 2 => 50,
 3 => 12
]
```

isn't valid JavaScript. The above gives you:

```
myArray = ["1", "50", "12"];
```

but if you want name/value pairs, probably an array of objects would be best:

```
myArray = [
 {name: "1", value: "1"},
 {name: "2", value: "50"},
 {name: "3", value: "12"}
]
```

To do that:

```
    var myArray = $.map(values, function(element) {
       return {name: element.name.substring(5, 6), value: element.value};
    });
```

Or of course if you want the whole name `item[1]`, just remove the `substring` part.

Example:

```js
$('button#despatchOrder').on('click', function() {
    var values = $("input.item");
    var myArray = $.map(values, function(element) {
       return {name: element.name.substring(5, 6), value: element.value};
    });
    console.log(myArray);
});
```

```html
<input name="item[1]" class="item" value="1">
<input name="item[2]" class="item" value="50">
<input name="item[3]" class="item" value="12">
<button id="despatchOrder">Despatch</button><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Just for completeness, you can also use the *other* `map` function (jQuery has two), but it doesn't do you any real good here:

```
var myArray = values.map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Note the `.get()` at the end.

Comment: @Dev.Wol: Updated (basically, you were looking for `element.name`), but you might also want to look at [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Answer (score 0):

javascript doesn't have associative array, but you can still access elements by numeric key

```
$('button#despatchOrder').on('click', function() {

    var values = $("input.items");

    var myArray = $.map(values, function(value, index) {
       return $(value).val();
    });

    console.log(myArray);
    console.log(myArray[0]);

});
```

if you want something similar to associative arrays you should use a js object

`{key:"value"}`